# Cascading select in Angular 1.x from Single JSON source

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement cascading `<select>` in angular from some json data.

Basically as soon as user selects a director then the movies dropdown is populated with that directors films.

However I am not sure how to access the set of childitems for a director in the json in the ng-repeat for the movies `<select>`

The selects are as follows. The first dropdown is populated on load with all director's id and name

```
<select name="directors" id="directors" ng-model="searchFilter.directorId">
    <option ng-repeat="item in directors" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
<select name="movies" id="movies" ng-disabled="!searchFilter.movieId" ng-model="searchFilter.movieId">
    <option ng-repeat="item in directors.childItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The json is

```
[{
        "childItems": [{
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Star Wars"
            }
        ],
        "id": 168,
        "name": "George Lucas"
    }, {
        "childItems": [{
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 10,
                "name": "The Hobbit"
            }, {
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 11,
                "name": "The Return of the King"
            }, {
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 30,
                "name": "Fellowship of the Ring"
            }
        ],
        "id": 170,
        "name": "Peter Jackson"
    }, {
        "childItems": [{
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Blade Runner"
            }
        ],
        "id": 167,
        "name": "Ridley Scott"
    }, {
        "childItems": [{
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "2001 A Space Odyssey"
            }
        ],
        "id": 279,
        "name": "Stanley Kubrick"
    }, {
        "childItems": [{
                "childItems": null,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Manhattan"
            }
        ],
        "id": 169,
        "name": "Woody Allen"
    }
]
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

this is easily accomplished by using `ng-options`.

```
<select name="directors" id="directors" ng-model="selectedDirector" 
        ng-options="item.name for item in movieList">
```

```
<select name="movies" id="movies" ng-disabled="!selectedDirector" ng-model="selectedMovie" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in selectedDirector.childItems">
```

Here we use the `selectedDirector` as the input object on the secondary dropdown.  In the secondary dropdown, we use the alternative form to bind `item.id` to the `ng-model`, while using the `item.name` for the label.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.movieList = [{
    "childItems": [{
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Star Wars"
    }],
    "id": 168,
    "name": "George Lucas"
  }, {
    "childItems": [{
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 10,
      "name": "The Hobbit"
    }, {
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 11,
      "name": "The Return of the King"
    }, {
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Fellowship of the Ring"
    }],
    "id": 170,
    "name": "Peter Jackson"
  }, {
    "childItems": [{
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Blade Runner"
    }],
    "id": 167,
    "name": "Ridley Scott"
  }, {
    "childItems": [{
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "2001 A Space Odyssey"
    }],
    "id": 279,
    "name": "Stanley Kubrick"
  }, {
    "childItems": [{
      "childItems": null,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Manhattan"
    }],
    "id": 169,
    "name": "Woody Allen"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <select name="directors" id="directors" ng-model="selectedDirector" ng-options="item.name for item in movieList">
  </select>
  <pre>{{selectedDirector}}</pre>
  <select name="movies" id="movies" ng-disabled="!selectedDirector" ng-model="selectedMovie" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in selectedDirector.childItems">
  </select>
  <pre>{{selectedMovie}}</pre>

</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qQVjhssFlFDXIzLm4LdQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to use whole director object in searchFilter and then reference it when building list of movies

```
<select name="directors" id="directors" ng-model="searchFilter.director">
    <option ng-repeat="item in directors" ng-value="item">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
<select name="movies" id="movies" ng-model="searchFilter.movieId">
    <option ng-repeat="item in searchFilter.director.childItems" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```